# Creating an ios distribution certificate

Tags: iphone

I would like to create an IOS Distribution certificate to distribute the app to the Apple store. When i create it, i should put in the User Email Address field,  the email address that matches the information that was submitted when you my client have registered as an iOS Developer. 
The problem that i don't know what he has entered ? how i can know the mail that he has entered ? the same thing for the company Name field.

I can't contact my clients, he is in holidays, but i have his username and password of his Apple Developer account.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: This question really belongs on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: Check out [the App Store proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Comment: What is Area51 ,please ? i need an answer please, help ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can login to Apple Dev Center and download new Certificates and install. You will find all the information you require there on the Dev Center.